# need help fixing an "illegal character 'u\600b'" error in Java

Tags: java

i am getting "illegal character '\u600b' in my return statement for the following code:

```
public static int getNum() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    boolean goodInput = true;    
    do {
        goodInput = true;
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter a positive number: "); // prompts the user
            number = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); // Tries to make the next input a number
        } catch (Exception e) { // if it breaks
            System.out.println("The number you entered was invalid."); // it tells the user it was wrong
            goodInput = false; // and runs the loop again
        }
        if(number <= 0) { // makes sure that the number entered was valid
            System.out.println("The number you entered was invalid.");
            goodInput = false; // or it re runs the loop
        }
    }while (!goodInput)

    ​return number;

}
```

any one know how to fix this?

Comment: I know this may sound odd, but could you delete the lines before and after the return statement, as well as the return statement, and then re-type it? (Copy-paste probably won't work)

Comment: ^^ That. You have garbage, non-printable characters you copy-and-pasted from somewhere.

Comment: Goddamn, it is so weird error, I am trying to reproduce it and it "works", but I do not know why!

Comment: Yeah, you're missing a semicolon on the do/while, and you almost certainly have some bogus character codes in there.  Usually such bogus character codes are due to using a word processor for a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

In looking at the Markdown source of your post, I found a stray non-printable character right before the `return`. You need to delete that entire line and retype it (or delete that character itself).

If you place the cursor between the r and the e, and press <kbd><-</kbd> a few times, you will see that the cursor does not move one of those times.